# Counter increment increases every time timer is restarted

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a simple game in excel, and I have a count up timer, but every time I click to regenerate a new game, the increment the timer counts up by increases by one. For example, when it's opened, it goes up by one every second, but when I reset the game, it counts up by twos, and if I reset it again, it counts by threes.

Here is the code that generates a new game:

```
Dim Counting As Boolean
Sub New_Game()
'
' New_Game Macro
' Generates a new game
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+n
'
    Call StopTimer
    Range("C6:K14").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("AM1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AM20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AN20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AO20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("AP21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("A1").Select
    Call StartTimer
End Sub
Sub StartTimer()
    Counting = True
    Call Increment
End Sub
Sub StopTimer()
    Counting = False
    Range("AH2") = 0
End Sub
Sub Increment()
    If Counting Then
        Application.OnTime (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")), "Increment"
        Range("AH2") = Range("AH2") + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

I can send the file if anyone needs it to understand what is happening.

Thanks

EDIT:
Updated code:

```
Dim Counting As Boolean
Dim earliest As Variant
Sub New_Game()
'
' New_Game Macro
' Generates a new game
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+n
'
    Call StopTimer
    Range("C6:K14").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("AM1:AP20,AP21").Formula = "=staticRAND()"
    Range("C6").Select
    Call StartTimer
End Sub
Sub StartTimer()
    'Counting = True
    Call Increment
End Sub
Sub StopTimer()
    'Counting = False
    Range("AH2") = 0
    Application.OnTime earliest, "Increment", , False
End Sub
Sub Increment()
    'If Counting Then
        earliest = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        Application.OnTime earliest, "Increment"
        Range("AH2") = Range("AH2") + 1
    'End If
End Sub
```

Now I'm getting a run-time error: Method 'OnTime' of object'_Application' failed

EDIT:

Opened it up this morning and it works perfectly.

Comment: I haven't looked at your question yet, but the whole of that large section of code can just be `Range("AM1:AP20,AP21").Formula = "=staticRAND()"`

Comment: Ok thanks. That does make sense and makes it better. And runs so much quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your NewGame() procedure calls StopTimer and later calls StartTimer. This will all happen much faster than 1 second, so the timer is never stopped - so you have two timers running, then, three, which is why the number increases.

I believe you need to explicitly cancel the previous timer using the `Schedule` argument of the `OnTime` method.

> expression.OnTime(EarliestTime, Procedure, LatestTime, Schedule)

You need a global variable to store the `EarliestTime`. This is necessary to cancel the timer based on both the procedure's name and its earliest time:

```
Dim earliest As Variant
```

In your Increment procedure you set this variable:

```
earliest = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.OnTime earliest, "Increment"
```

Then, in your StopTimer procedure, you can cancel the previous timer:

```
Application.OnTime earliest, "Increment", , False
```

There is probably no need for your `Counting` variable now.

Comment: Is this what you mean:

`Sub StopTimer()`
    `Counting = False`
    `Range("AH2") = 0`
    `Application.OnTime earliest, "Increment", , False`
`End Sub`
`Sub Increment()`
    `If Counting Then`
        `earliest = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")`
        `Application.OnTime earliest, "Increment"`
        `Range("AH2") = Range("AH2") + 1`
    `End If`
`End Sub`

Because I get a run-time error:
    Method 'OnTime' of object'_Application' failed

Comment: I can't read that clearly. You could add it to the bottom of your first post. Anyway, earliest needs to be a global variable (like your Counting variable) and needs to be assigned a value before you attempt to use it with OnTime.

Comment: Ok then thanks. I couldn't work out how to make it look nice. I think I did what you mean, but am not sure